# Placeholder as an option

Tags: javascript, placeholder, selectize.js

When you create a dropdown using selectize, once you select an option, the only way to select the placeholder is by clicking the input field & then hitting the backspace which is not intuitive. Can we have the placeholder as an option similar to how it is in the native select element ?

Similar problem is referenced in this [github issue](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/163)

Comment: It'll be helpful, if people explain when they downvote a question.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a selectize plugin for this problem, which appends the placeholder element which on click will clear the selection.

```
Selectize.define('selectable_placeholder', function( options ) {
    var self = this;

    options = $.extend({
        placeholder: self.settings.placeholder,
        html: function ( data ) {
            return (
                '<div class="selectize-dropdown-content placeholder-container">' +
                    '<div data-selectable class="option">' + data.placeholder + '</div>' +
                '</div>'
            );
        }
    }, options );

    // override the setup method to add an extra "click" handler
    self.setup = (function() {
        var original = self.setup;
        return function() {
            original.apply(this, arguments);
            self.$placeholder_container = $( options.html( options ) );
            self.$dropdown.prepend( self.$placeholder_container );
            self.$dropdown.on( 'click', '.placeholder-container', function () {
                self.setValue( '' );
                self.close();
                self.blur();
            });
        };
    })();

});
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mudassir0909/a6396fdbe528fbe6fbeb)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unspecified/Zw8vm/)

Hope this helps someone who might run into this issue.